# Are there any treasures beneath the ocean surface?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

There are a lot of areas with water in Skyrim, but is there any reason for me to go skinny dipping in the bone chilling water?

Is there any notable treasure (or any other items) or old shipwrecks that I can only find by diving?

Comment: There's plenty of delicious fish eggs and barnacles down there

Comment: I found an enchanted daedric bow there!

Comment: There's a mod that adds SEA MONSTERS! :O

Answer (score 25, accepted):

First off, [this is what you should expect to find](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KwtA.jpg) as a reward for underwater exploration. There aren't many underwater enemies, certainly no dangerous ones. Aside from too much water. I haven't explored enough to post a truly definitive answer, but I can think of a few, none of which are like [Goldbrand](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Boethiah%27s_Quest) or [Fin Gleam](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Unique_Items#Unique_Helmets). Hopefully there's something more, because this list (and note, it's impossible to be definitive when so much of Skyrim is water) is not very impressive.

The most significant one I've found is the treasure for [Treasure Map X](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Treasure_Map_X), which is in the pond near the Lady Stone.

For something requiring Waterbreathing, there's the [Pilgrim's Trench](http://content2.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Pilgrim%27s_Trench), a ship graveyard with some decent loot.

There is a [minor quest in Ivarstead](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Straw_that_Broke) that requires looking underwater, but it's barely waist deep.

There are three underwater chests in [Broken Oar Grotto](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Broken_Oar_Grotto), memorable to me because the Moon Amulet (a minor Radiant Quest) was locked in a Master Chest on the deck of a sunken ship. The same is true in many caves (although usually fewer chests), but nothing major.

[There's a notable false positive at Hela's Folly](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Hela's_Folly); the item you need for a quest is actually on dry ground near the shipwreck. The ship has a chest or two, though.

As for places that are below sea level but not filled with water, [the Wreck of the Winter War](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Winter_War) contains a skill book and [Ilinalta's Deep](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Ilinalta%27s_Deep) is related to a Daedric quest.

Comment: + 1 good answer. I would recommend carrying a waterbreathing potion or two if you want to explore beneath the waves of Skyrim.

Comment: @Coomie Right. Also, Volsung (an easily accessible Dragon Priest mask) gives you waterbreathing plus 20 more capacity, which is nice so you don't get overburdened underwater. Argonians, of course, can breathe underwater as a racial trait.

Comment: @lol at the graphic, that's classic!

Answer (score 1):

In this Dwemer cave, not sure which 1 but it was one of the first ones (if not the first) you enter along the main storyline, in this room with some pathways above a body of water I found an underwater room filled with treasure. Also with the Dawnguard plugin in the Hidden Vale in this cave full of Falmer (river runs along it), at the bottom of this 1 part theres a deep hole of water with a tunnel inside which leads to a chest full of loot. The ship in the Top Voted guy's picture also has about 1000-1500 worth of gems laying on the floor inside if it's the one I think it is in the far northern waters.

Answer (score 0):

I've spent quite a bit of time exploring, and I have never found very much underwater. Your best bet is to explore shipwrecks.